# Why should we stop using Ibatis and start using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, ibatis

Preparing a proposal for my team,  I have the obvious ones.

Ibatis is retired, no more fixes/enhancements.
Hibernate is the de-factor standard.
Hibernate has more/better documentation.

What would add or take away from the proposal?

Thanks

Comment: I think your facts might be out of date ibatis has been reborn as mybatis: http://www.mybatis.org/

Comment: There are just too many dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984548/hibernate-vs-ibatis, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762643/hibernate-vs-ibatis, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716532/hibernate-ibatis-jee-or-other-java-orm-tool, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747413/hibernate-or-ibatis-or-something-else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is dynamic, generated SQL.  If it works for you, great.  Some people don't like the SQL they get from Hibernate.  iBatis gives you control over the SQL that's used.

Hibernate makes no sense if you don't have a good object model.

I'm not sure I agree that Hibernate is a de-facto standard.

How much more documentation do you need?  Is the iBatis documentation sufficient?

Some problems are "done".  Maybe iBatis is complete.  What features do you think are needed to be added?

Comment: iBatis isn't complete, it's just been renamed and moved to http://www.mybatis.org/  It's got a whole lot of new features too.